# Post build on database project

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, database-project

In Visual Studio 2008, I have this database project to manage my SQL Server 2008 database. This has a prebuild and postbuild SQL Script that contains an example like this:

```
:r .\myfile.sql
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword missing from your google search was "sqlcmd".

The "r" command is used to include the contents of another SQL file at that location; the parameter passed in is the relative file path of the included file.

See [MSDN docs for sqlcmd syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833281.aspx) for more information.